# CakePhp Access Multiple Tables in One Custom Model

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Hello Dear StackOverflowers, I am new to Cake PHP. I want to access two tables students and teachers in Same Model. How to do that ? Cake bake produces Controllers, Models and Views for only ONE TABLE. I dont want to use a third Model to access them if it is possible to use one Model to access two tables. 
Thanks.

Comment: You should have a model for each table. Then you can call whatever model from whatever model

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to accomplish (i.e, the business problem statement)? Technically, only one table can be used as the basis for a model, but there are techniques to add other tables (e.g., using SQL views, JOIN clause in QUERY method). These techniques come with limitations.

Comment: Thanks AgRizzo for your quick Response. I want to Display the data form both my Tables on a single Page but Cake created Two Controllers, Two Models and Two Views and both has their own chains.

Comment: Do you have a relationship between these two tables? It is extremely common to use one Controller to get data from multiple models, especially when there is a relationship - it's inherent to the `find` method. If there is not a relationship, in the Student controller use this code `$this->loadModel('Teacher');`.  Now in the Student controller you can write code that uses that model (e.g., `$this->Teacher->find('all');`

Comment: No I dont have any Relationship in both tables. and If I use my custom Controller can I delete the Controllers and Views created by Cake Bake ? I think I need only models to access data.

Comment: @Meer **do the blog tutorial** http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples.html and read the book. Having multiple models doesn't prevent you from fetching associated data. For example the association "teacher has many students" would allow you to return a teacher and all his students with a single method call. See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html and http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html

Comment: @Meer - Welcome to StackOverflow! :) As you use SO, you will find that we will be both more likely and better able to help you if we can see what you tried. There are two reasons for this: (1) we can see that you have put in the effort so we will be willing to put in the effort as well (2) we can more accurately point you in the right direction. As it stands, there is too little information for this question to be valid on SO, as it is too broad, given the details in the OP (original post).

Comment: @Zachary Kniebel - Thanks Dear StackOverflower. I was in the learning process and was stuck on this point when I tried a real example. I stated here EXACT PROBLEM. I dont understand how to be more specific. Accessing TWO TABLES in my own CUSTOM MODEL. Isnt it Specific ?

Comment: @Meer you question doesn't show any effort (code, research) and IMHO as well that you haven't even bothered to spend some time with reading about the very basics.

Comment: @burzum. It is your assumption. I have already ready the CookBook and the pages you mentioned but they dont mention somthing about my problem. I rechecked the Cook Book when I stuck on this problem and searched GOOGLE for help and even StackOverflow but didnt find an answer. I am also SPENDING TIME to read the Asnwers and Comments here and trying to clarify my problem. And Between this time while commenting on SO (StackOverflow) I HAVE FOUND MY ANSWER. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's good approach, because it's against convention one table - one model, but of course is up to you. You can change table on the fly using public field `$useTable`.

```
$this->ModelName->useTable = 'table_name';
```

So in that case you have to set this variable each time you perform any action on database. Instead just calling `$this->ModelName->find();` you have to always add extra line before `find()` statement to make sure that your queries go to appropriate table.

Comment: Thanks dear marian0 for a quick answer. from ModelName in the expression you mean my Custom Model? and as you mentioned a convention one table - one model, so should I access each Table with one Model and then access both tables with a Third model ? or just use these models in my controller ?

Comment: Yes, I mean your custom model by `ModelName`. So it's depends what kind of data you need to access, but in most cases you just need to use your models in controller. If you have realtions between to tables, you can setup them in one model and then you just call this particular model and you have data from all your definded models.

Comment: I accepted your advice and used one Model for each of my tables and understood that a Model then behave like I am directly contacting with a Table. I created my own Controller and My Own View and Deleted Views and Controllers created by Cake Bake. Thanks again.